# why and when t0 use norm instead of abs and vice versa

Tags: normed-spaces, absolute-value

What is the difference between the norm and abs of  an expression..

as far i understand does ||a - z|| mean norm and |a-z| abs , but what is the difference?

Comment: the *absolute value* has a specific definition. the *norm* can have multiple definitions, depending on context. the absolute value is a norm, but a norm is not necessarily an absolute value. You might even see people "abuse notation" and use the absolute value bars in place of norm bars.

Comment: abs is only for the reals and complex. On other spaces, you use the norm of the space

Comment: in simple words norm generalizes the absolute value.

Comment: what would ||a-z|| than mean and what would |a-z| mean ?

Comment: and more confusing: the absolute value notation often is used to describe the euklidean $2$-norm in $\mathbb{R}^n$